# Select value from dropdown list, filter result and download file in loop

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is put javascript functions in loop:

1. select option from drop down
2. click on "Filter" button
3. download selected file

When i have it in two functions it works perfectly:  - no loop, running manually (index from 0 until x)

```
function chooseOpt(x){
document.getElementsByClassName('span4 m-wrap dropdown combobox')[1].selectedIndex = x;
const links = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn green'));
links.forEach((link) => {
  if (link.textContent === 'Filter') {
    link.click();
  }
})
}
    
function Dowload(){
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn icn-only black tooltips download_link')[0];
button.click();
}
```

But how can i put into loop?
i ve created one function from this two, but doesnt work:

```
function chooseOpt(){
    for (x = 0; x<3;x++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('span4 m-wrap dropdown combobox')[1].selectedIndex = x;
    const links = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn green'));
    var button  = document.getElementsByClassName('btn icn-only black tooltips download_link')[0];
    links.forEach((link) => {
      if (link.textContent === 'Filter') {
        link.click();
      }
    }
    )
      button.click();
    }
}

chooseOpt();
```

Can you give me hint, link ?  Thank you

Comment: What does "Put it in a loop" mean exactly?

Comment: Hi, it means i wont  write  x  - selectedIndex manually ..... but function will loop from  0 to 125 for example .... so  selectedIndex = 1, then filter result after that download file,  next selectedIndex = 2 , then filter result after that download file,  next selectedIndex = 3,  next selectedIndex = 4 next selectedIndex = 5 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing your HTML made it a bit challenging, but I contrived some markup that works with your script structure, then modified the script to successfully:

- Loop through all options,
- Simulate an associated `link` click for each option, and
- Simulate a `button` click for each option to download an associated file

**I encountered the same problem you did**, and I was able to make it go away by adding a custom-event listener on the `dropdown` element. At least part of the issue for me was that **programmatically changing the `selectedIndex` property of a `select` element does not trigger event listeners** like calling the `.click` method on certain elements does. To make sure that the `download` function is called for each option, the code below employs a custom event (called `programmatic-selection`), which is triggered manually in the `chooseOpt` function.

**Other things to note:**

- Each `link` has a **`data-file` attribute that stores the path to the associated file**. This value is copied to a global `filepath` variable when needed so the `button` can see which file to download.
- Each **`link` will be clicked if it has a class matching the current `option`**'s text content. (Your code selects `link`s based on `link.textContent === 'Filter'`, and this behavior is preserved: any `link` that matches the current `option` has its `textContent` property set to 'Filter' in order to meet your condition and thereby trigger a simulated click.)

```js
// Declares global variables
const
  dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[1],
  links = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn')),
  button = document.getElementsByClassName('download-link')[0];
let filepath = '';

// Adds event listeners
dropdown.addEventListener('programmatic-selection', handleProgrammaticSelection);
document.addEventListener('click', handleLinkClick);
button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);

// Main
chooseAll();

// Loops through options, selecting each one
function chooseAll(){
  let i = -1;
  while(++i < dropdown.length){
    chooseOpt(i);
  }
}

// Triggers custom event listener and the appropriate link
function chooseOpt(x){
  dropdown.selectedIndex = x;
  // The `change` event won't fire if we select an option 
  //   programmatically, so we fire a custom event instead
  dropdown.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('programmatic-selection'));
  links.forEach((link) => {
    if(link.textContent === 'Filter'){
      // Simulates click on certain links, triggering listener
      link.click();
    }
  });
}

// Listener for custom event -- sets link text
function handleProgrammaticSelection(event){
  const dropdown = event.target;
  links.forEach((link) => {
    // `chooseOpt` relies on `textContent` property of `link` elements,
    //   so we set this before deciding which link to click
    link.textContent = link.classList.contains(dropdown.value)
      ? 'Filter'
      : 'Nope';
  });
}

// (Listeners can automatically access their triggering events)
function handleLinkClick(event){

  // An event has a `target` property
  const clickedThing = event.target;

  // Ignores irrelevant clicks
  if(!clickedThing.classList.contains('btn')){ return; }

  // Sets global `filepath` to match 'file' data-attribute of target
  filepath = clickedThing.dataset.file;

  // Calls `download`, which simulates button click
  download();
}

// Called by above listener
function download(){
  // Simulates click on `button`, triggering listener
  button.click();
}

// Called by listener on `button`
function handleButtonClick(event){
  // Accesses global `filepath` to pick file
  console.log(`downloading ${filepath}...`);
}
```

```html
<select class="dropdown">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
</select><br/>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option>AA</option>
  <option>BB</option>
  <option>CC</option>
</select><br/><br/>

<button data-file='some-file' class='btn AA'>Nope</button><br/>
<button data-file='some-other-file' class='btn BB'>Nope</button><br/>
<button data-file='another-file' class='btn CC'>Nope</button><br/><br/>

<button class='download-link'>Download</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question kind of doesn't make sense but, I think this is what you might want...

```js
function chooseOpt(x){
      document.getElementsByClassName('span4 m-wrap dropdown combobox')[1].selectedIndex = x;
      const links = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn green'));
      var button  = document.getElementsByClassName('btn icn-only black tooltips download_link')[0];
      links.forEach((link) => {
        if (link.textContent === 'Filter') {
          link.click();
        }
    });
    button.click();
}



for(let x = 0; i < 3; x++){
  chooseOpt(x);
}
```